# Trigger causes insert to fail

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

i create a trigger in MSSQL on a table of web application. The problem is that after I created this trigger I get an error when I try to submit a form.
Web application works as a social network and sends messages. I want to send this messegaes by SMS to recipients of this messages. So mz trigger makes insert of text and number of recipients in SMSServer.
Can you pls help me to fix it?

Here is my trigger:

```
create trigger trigger_ZpravyMonoxViaSMS on [dbo].[SnMessageRecipient] 
after insert  as
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @text as nvarchar(160)
DECLARE @calledstatio nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @ms int
SET @id = (select top 1 i.messageid from inserted i)
SET @text = (select left(Body,160) 
             from SnMessage s 
             join SnMessageRecipient sr on s.id = sr.MessageId 
             where s.id = @id)
SET @calledstatio = (select '420'+tolist 
                     from SnMessage s 
                     join SnMessageRecipient sr on s.id = sr.MessageId
                     where s.id = @id)
SET @ms = (select i.messagestatus from inserted i where i.MessageId = @id)
if @ms like '1'
begin
insert into [SQL].[SMSServer].[dbo].[MessageOut]( messageto
              ,messagefrom
              ,messagetext
              ,messageType
              ,gateway
              ,userid
              ,isread
              ,issent)
values (@calledstatio, '', @text, '', 'GSM', '1', '0','0')
end
```

Comment: what kind of error it is showing ??

Comment: Error is: An error has occured while trying to send the message to the following recipient: [RecipientName].

Comment: The trigger seems to be fine.

Comment: can you please try into DB side means in table side .just check with the MessageOut table data is inserting or not

Comment: it doesn`t, trigger can`t insert data into dbo.[MessageOut], because nothing was inserted into dbo.[SnMessageRecipient], trigger just lock the database

Answer (score 0):

The trigger has several problems:

- it would send only one message, even if you inserted 100 messages at once (could be okay, if you are 100 % sure that only single row inserts happens)
- it would fail if you have more than one recipient per id because you have no TOP 1 in the set @calledstatio statement
- even, if you add the TOP 1 it would mean that you would send messages only to one recipient (and depending on the execution plan it can differ to which one)

Edit: beside of this your error message seems to come from the trigger on the MessageOut table. You should try to insert a record manual into this table. And maybe you want to use the debug mode (startet with F11) or print out the content of your variables to see, what you really try to insert.

Comment: Ì have tried to insert manually data into [dbo].[SnMessageRecipient] table, and recieve this error 'Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trigger_ZpravyMonoxViaSMS, Line 10
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated. '

Comment: So, what i wrote previosly, i fix it. Now i can insert data manually into table dbo.[SnMessageRecipients], and message sends ok. But it still doesnt work via web portal :(